# Solomonoff induction generates sequences of unbounded Kolmogorov complexity?

Tags: turing-machines, kolmogorov-complexity

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01826), and the author (in private correspondence, though I'm sure it's also in the paper) explains that a bit string generated through Solomonoff induction will have growing (and unbounded) Kolmogorov complexity.

This sounds counterintuitive to me: Solomonoff induction tends to favor bit strings that have *lower* K-complexity (all else being equal). Is there an intuitive way to understand this apparent contradiction?

Secondly, he claims that the resulting string will with high likelihood appear to have been generated by a *simple* program, in the sense that the program would produce this output *if fed a random bit string.* As an example, the program that just prints its input will produce a uniformly random output given uniformly random input. Following the logic backward, since this is a simple program, a uniformly random output has a relatively high chance of being generated by Solomonoff induction.

It might be that there is no simpler way to understand these results than to understand the provided paper in greater detail, but I'm finding it difficult to work through all the details. I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.